# Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this part of code

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

Its better to accept my mistake with this question. I messed up things thats why i had this problem. Sorry for bothering you people ...

```
string name = ((DateTimePicker)sender).Name.ToString();
        name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - 1);
        name = name + "4";
        TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan();
        duration = ((DateTimePicker)sender).Value - ((DateTimePicker)panel2.Controls[name]).Value;
        name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - 1);
        name = name + "6";
        ((MaskedTextBox)panel2.Controls[name]).Text = duration.ToString();
```

On execution it gives me Object reference not set to instance of an object 
similar functionality is used on other places but I can't find out what I have to reinitialize here :$

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/735eefb5db.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/735eefb5db.jpg)

The casting for datetimepicker is fine 
I have to get a name for the datetiempicker to identify the row it's on in my form 
and the picker before that to calculate their differences and then print that difference in a maskedtext box from the control whose name I make using names of two datetimepickers but when I access controls in the error line I get this message.

Comment: You need to be more specific, exactly what line is it that throws the exception?

Comment: What are u doing with name?  Its impossible for us to tell without knowing the details.  Just attach the debugger, and step over each line where you retrieve a control.  One of them is null.

Comment: Like Nix says, step over the lines and you'll find the error...it's either panel2.Controls[name] or panel2 itself...hmm...maybe senders null????

Comment: no its not null i have checked in debugger .. and if it would b null then it would generate an error in first line not 5th i guess

Comment: @Mobin...you're right re sender...then it seems it would be panel2.Controls[name]...select that while debugging and right click and select QuickWatch and see what it says.

Comment: This is just bad coding practice altogether!  You're trying to get names of controls by taking a current object, substringing the last character off, and appending a new number?  I cry a little inside every time I see code like this...

Comment: @Doug - Yes, I hope I never have to be exposed to this application outside of this context.

Comment: Ok id i agree with you both @Doug and @stingyJack then consider the scenario when you have to save multiple records in a table and you can't tell how much then i used this thing to display all at the same time whether updating or adding new. This was thing i figured out to show rather than a form having 5 input fields and updating them and showing an empty form again to enter 6th one but thats my idea if have better solution its appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots...

Use String.Format() to make this a little clearer. It's OK to not use StringBuilder for this, but it's real hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Also, things like the

```
(DateTimePicker)sender
```

Should not be repeated. Cast once, and reuse the cast object.

```
DateTimePicker _castObject = (DateTimePicker)sender;
```

The obj not ref error could be on any of these objects. Unless you step through, or add defensive statements (below), you are going to have a heck of a time figuring it out.

```
if (sender == null)
{ throw new ArgumentNullException("sender", "sender is null");}
```

If this is happening in a standard event handler on your form, it would look something like this (excuse the VB, I cant do c# from memory anymore).

```
Protected Function btnOK_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
 'your code'
End Function
```

If you see something similar, then there is no reason to cast any object on the form. Just access it by its control name (btnOK, txtMaskedTextBox, etc).

You seem to be going about something here in an entirely wrong way. Perhaps you should start by explaining the actual problem you are trying to solve instead of this specific exception. See "[thin metal ruler](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/03/a-parable.aspx)".

Comment: Can you help more on the point that i should use casting once ... but don't you think that would make a separate object for that and i won't be able to access the object on my form

Comment: You are using the sender 3x and casting it 3x. This causes extra work to be done. Cast it once, and use the casted result. What do you mean "wont be able to access the object on my form"? Maybe you should post more of the method so we can see exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I meant that if a control named MaskedTextBox1 is on your form and you cast it and save that in another object then you can't access the MaskedTextBox1 from that casted object. I tried what you said but then i have to recalculate to get to my control MaskedTextBox1 try it you will understand that. Or you find how to reference that to casted object do let me know

Answer (score 0):

Check that you formed the "name" correctly and a control with that name exists. And that panel2 isn't null.

Comment: ya i have done that ... thats why i spend lot of time doing those checks before asking such a foolish question but thats what making me bother... to confirm i would say if panel2 doesn't exist then line 7 wont work in my given code and yes i have checked the 'name' does exist